# SMTP HELO command from Windows gives 500 Command unrecognized error, same command from Linux returns Hello

Tags: smtp, sendmail

We have a Java web application that needs to send out emails to our users, and I'm getting this Java error when those emails try to go out:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: hostname.example.com, port: 25, response: 421
```

I began troubleshooting this Exception by trying some SMTP commands over telnet to our `sendmail` server. I'm seeing strange discrepancies between how it interacts with a Linux server and a Windows Server.

On Linux, I can run:

`telnet hostname.example.com 25`

and the result is:

```
220 ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
HELO hostname.example.com
250 hostname.example.com Hello [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx], pleased to meet you
```

(xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is replacing the IP address I ran the `telnet` command from, but the asterisks are *not* obfuscating anything -- that's exactly what the command output)

However, on Windows Server, on the same subnet, vlan, Windows Firewall disabled, I get the following:

`telnet hostname.example.com 25`

gives me:

```
220 *********************************************************************************************************************************************************
********************
HELO hostname.example.com
500 5.5.1 Command unrecognized: "XXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

(neither the `*` or `X` were obfuscated in the above output -- this is exactly what the command output)

There are no proxies between the Linux/Windows clients, and the `sendmail` server.

Comment: Are you using RDS or something like that for accessing Windows? Is there any way how to run in directly from console?

Comment: I'm running through RDS and typing directly into a `cmd`.

Comment: Maybe telnet has problem with remote keyboard (yep, I've seen it before, application gets nonsense keycodes) and so there is bullshit on telnet's input => bullshit sended to SMTP. Try to do it from real keyboard directly connected to Windows station to eliminate effect of RDS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this was a firewall issue. Our Cisco firewall was set to perform ESMTP Inspection, and we followed [this guide](http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000536.htm) to disable it.